How can I dismiss the keyboard when tapping anywhere on the screen except on the text field using FocusState?
I am passing FocusState property(focusField) from (TextFieldObservers) view to customTextFieldView through binding.
Aim: on tapping on the TextFieldObservers View, the keyboard should dismiss?
Problem: On taping the textfield in TextFieldObservers View, keyboard also dismissing. Which is not required?
below is my code.
 import SwiftUI
   import Foundation

    enum Placeholder: Hashable {
        case email
        case password
        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .email: return "email"
            case .password: return "password"
            }
        }
        func nextControl() -> Placeholder {
            return switch self {
            case .email: .password
            case .password: .email
            }
        }
    }

    struct TextFieldObservers: View {
        @FocusState var focusedField: Placeholder?
        @State var flag: Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    CustomTextField(placeHolder: .email,
                                    description: "",
                                    focusedField: $focusedField)
                    CustomTextField(placeHolder: .password,
                                    description: "", focusedField: $focusedField)
                }
                .background(Color.green)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                focusedField = nil
            }
        }
        
    }

    struct CustomTextField: View {
        var placeHolder: Placeholder
        @State var description: String
        @FocusState.Binding var focusedField: Placeholder?
        
        init(placeHolder: Placeholder, 
             description: String,
             focusedField: FocusState<Placeholder?>.Binding) {
            self.placeHolder = placeHolder
            self.description = description
            self._focusedField = focusedField
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            TextField(placeHolder.description, text: $description)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                        .fill(.white)
                }
                .focused($focusedField, equals: placeHolder)
                .submitLabel(.next)
                .onSubmit {
                    focusedField = placeHolder.nextControl()
                }
        }
    }

    #Preview {
        TextFieldObservers()
    }


KeyBoard should persist on clicking the textfield and disappear clicking anywhere in the View. I know that i can use a function like this, but my aim is to avoid UIkit.
func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }


To dismiss the keyboard when tapping anywhere on the screen except on the text field using FocusState in SwiftUI, you can follow these steps:

Use a @FocusState property wrapper to manage the focus state of your text field.

Add a tap gesture to your main view that will dismiss the keyboard when the user taps outside of the text field.


Here is an example implementation:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background view to detect taps
            Color.clear
                .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Makes the whole area tappable
                .onTapGesture {
                    isTextFieldFocused = false
                }

            // Your main content
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()

                // Other UI elements
                Text("Tap outside the text field to dismiss the keyboard")
                    .padding()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

When the text field is focused (i.e., the keyboard is visible), tapping on the Color.clear area will set isTextFieldFocused to false, causing the text field to lose focus and the keyboard to be dismissed.

.contentShape(Rectangle()) is it necessary to add this?

if you use a construction with Color.clear yes, but there are different ways to do it. It's just a working example, you can play with it to see how it works and to find a better way that suits your needs
